# Asp.Net: Scroll to Validation error of Validation Callout Extender?

Tags: asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit, extender

Is it possible to Scroll to the Validation error of the ValidationCalloutExtender?

I have a large page sometimes when I click on a button on the top of the page and If I forgot to enter something in one field located at the end of the page I can't know what exactly is happening on the page unless I happen to scroll down and see the ValidationCalloutExtender popup, is there a way to scroll to the field where the ValidationCalloutExtender has been triggered?

Answer (score 2):

Place this script at very bottom of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var originalShow = Sys.Extended.UI.ValidatorCalloutBehavior.prototype.show;
    Sys.Extended.UI.ValidatorCalloutBehavior.prototype.show = function (force) {
        this._elementToValidate.scrollIntoView(false); //true to align with the top of the scroll area
        originalShow.call(this, force);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: The script does force the page to move to the correct position but it does not respect the PopupPosition property of the ValidatorCalloutExtender, I noticed that it puts the popup on random locations.